# Syncing SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer to absolute position

Tags: c++, superpowered

`SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer` has built in beat syncing which works well. But I want to sync the player to the absolute position of my metronome and tried to do so by setting this position with the players `setPosition (double ms, bool andStop, bool synchronisedStart)` method in every processing loop. This works as long as the player plays in its original bpm. When I change the tempo and the playback gets timestretched I get distorted audio.

I tried to set the position to the position of the master as well as to the calculated position of the player in its original tempo (`masterPositionMs` * `playerBpm` / `masterBpm`). I also tried this with beat synchronization on and off.

What am I doing wrong? Any better way to do absolute syncing?

```
bool MyAudioSession::process(short int *in_out, unsigned int numberOfInputSamples) {

  float currentBPM = metronome->getBpm();
  double msElapsedSinceLastMasterBeat = metronome->getMsElapsedSinceLastBeat();
  double msPositionMaster = metronome->getPositionMs();
  bool silence = true;

  if(metronome->process(stereoOutputBuffer, !silence, numberOfInputSamples, volMetronome))
      silence = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < audioPlayers.size(); i++) {
      if(audioPlayers[i]->playing) {
          audioPlayers[i]->setPosition(
                  (msPositionMaster * audioPlayers[i]->bpm / currentBPM) + audioPlayers[i]->firstBeatMs,
                  !metronome->isPlaying(),
                  SYNCHRONISED_START);
      }

      if(audioPlayers[i]->process(stereoOutputBuffer, !silence, numberOfInputSamples, audioPlayers[i]->volume, currentBPM, msElapsedSinceLastMasterBeat))
          silence = false;

  }

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for setPosition, the player will sync to the next beat. Just call play(true) for a re-sync.

Comment: Hi Gabor I have general beat sync running, no problem with that. But I want to sync to an absolute position not only to the beat grid. I get the absolute `msPositionMaster` and `currentBPM` from my custom metronome class. I want all the players to sync to its absolute position. Tempo should also be adjusted to the metronome but will not change during playback. When I use `setPosition` what position is needed? Pre or post timestretch position?

Comment: The player always tracks position properly regardless time stretching. Position should reflect the position to start playback from. Make sure that position falls onto your custom beatgrid though!